# What kind of tree is this that has letters as nodes?

Tags: string, data-structures, tree, trie

I just started learning C++ and I need to create a tree of lists (Image link below) for a project but I'm not sure if it is a custom tree or a preexisting tree.

A bit on the tree; big blue blocks represent lists, smaller blocks inside represent nodes.

I am not looking for code or anything, just an explanation of the tree or links to where I could find information on it.

[image: Image Here]

Comment: I think it can be achieved by the [Linux Kernel Linked List](https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)

Comment: Try to describe the image. That alone will probably bring you close to an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure in the image is Trie data structure.
**Trie is an efficient information retrieval data structure. Using trie, search complexities can be brought to optimal limit (key length).** - (Source :  GeeksForGeeks)
Trie shown in the image is made for the following strings - 
Act, Actual, Actually, And, Book, Boss, Bore, Board and Boat.
Some useful links to know more -

- [Trie from
  Hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/trie-keyword-tree/tutorial/)
- [Trie From GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/)
- [Trie From Topcoder](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-tries/)
- [Youtube Video on Tries](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwisxL6G9sHUAhXGLo8KHUZ7A7MQtwIIazAN&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DAXjmTQ8LEoI&usg=AFQjCNFf8oB67gJpKxZwNBF3K1m0CztubQ&sig2=RIWH4pZTnMOnvxJJN0j8Dg)

Answer (score 0):

From the picture I'd use something like

```
struct List;
struct Node {
    // ... node data ...
    std::shared_ptr<List> list;
};
struct List {
    // ... list data ...
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
};
```

unless the number of nodes in a list can be huge and you need to dynamically insert/remove nodes from the middle of a list.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a costume tree to me. Usually for projects they make their own costume tree that is a combination of data structures. for example this is a combination of lists, and linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is an implementation of a Trie, or a prefix tree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

The levels can be implemented in different ways: linked lists, bitmaps, arrays, etc. But the idea behind them is the same.